# Regex syntax: <script> from html document

Tags: regex

```
 \b(?<=(\<script\>))(.*[\s\S]*?)(?=(\<\/script>))\b
```

This is my regex. It doesn't work. But if I delete those symbols:

**\>** at left side

and

**\<\/** at right side

regex work:

```
 \b(?<=(\<script))(.*[\s\S]*?)(?=(script>))\b
```

But it's not what I need.

Any idea?

Comment: It's small html with one big script block. I don't parse html using regex ;)

Comment: What's the regex implementation? Is it .Net Regex?

Comment: Now I test regex on this [service](http://www.regexr.com).
But in result I need .net regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what You are looking for ?

```
(?<=\<script\>)(.*[\s\S]*?)(?=\<\/script\>)
```

Comment: Yes. But I don't understand why this regex didn't work in my .net application...
Maybe because I didn't sleep last night :/
Thanks a lot

Comment: Final .Net regex:

    `string pattern = @"(?<=<script>)(.*[\s\S]*?)(?=</script>)";`

Comment: What is the purpose of `[\s\S]*`  ? Isn't that equivalent to `.*`  ?

Comment: Final .Net regex from my last comment can be simplified: `string pattern = @"(?<=<script>)([\s\S]*?)(?=</script>)";`.        Martin, no. `.*` means any symbol except for new line symbol (but it can include new line symbol in some imlementations by using additional option. Examples: `RegexOptions.Multiline` in .Net, `re.DOTALL` in Python). `\s` means any whitespace symbol ([ \t\n\r\f\v]). `\S` means any not-whitespace symbol ([^ \t\n\r\f\v]). In result `[\s\S]*` means any count of any symbols, everything.